# How to declare a variable using a string?

Tags: c#, string

I need to declare a variable with a name that matches a string.

This is what I need to work, but in reality it compiles with a new expression instance with the name `"s"` (I need it to take the name that is stored in the string s)
How can I solve this?

Code:

```
foreach (string s in StringArray)
            {
                if (SomeDifferentArray.Contains(s) != true)
                {
                    Expression s = new Expression(); 
                }
            }
```

I need a new instance of expression for each string in `StringArray`, and each of those expressions needs to be named according to the literal that the string holds.

Comment: You should probably tag this as C# or mention that this is C# somehwere (At least, I'm guessing it's C#)

Comment: *"This is what I need to work"* - No, it's what you *think* you need. In reality it would be a very poor solution.  Tying your program logic to variable names (which don't even exist once your program is compiled) would lead to nothing more than unmaintainable code.  You want a collection, probably a mapping of strings to whatever.

Comment: you probably have a design problem, rather than this question. You dont wanna do things like that. review your design.

Comment: Marko could elaborate in greater detail, how you're going to use this in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a use case for a mapping collection. I'm not a C# user myself but I suspect the dictionary class would be the one to go to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

C# is a compiled language, so you can't create compile-time variables that are dependent on run-time data. However, you can use a map-style data structure to associate a unique key object with a single value object. In your case, you can use it to associate each `string` with a single `Expression`.

```cs
Dictionary<string, Expression> myExpressionDict = new Dictionary<string, Expression>();

foreach(string s in StringArray) {
    if(!SomeDifferentArray.Contains(s)) {
        myExpressionDict[s] = new Expression();
    }
}
```

After this loop finishes, for any string `s` in your original `SomeArray`, you can do `myExpressionDict[s]` to get its associated `Expression` object.

In C# this structure is called a "dictionary." This same data struture may also go by the names "map" or "hash," depending on your programming language or library. For example, in the Java collections framework it's referred to as Map, in Ruby they use the term hash, and in Python it goes by the name dictionary (or dict for short).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Map or a Dictionary.  Not exactly what you are asking but a lot more simple.